# How to load GUID values from one DB to Another DB using SSIS

Tags: dynamics-crm, etl, ssis

I have two CRM's MS CRM 2011 (on-premise with SQL server 2008) and MS CRM 2011 (in the cloud).

I want to migrate data from on-premise to online using SSIS 2008, were i installed a third party components like "CRM Source Component" and "CRM Destination Component". Here when i'm trying to map all attribute from source to destination except auto generated fields(GUID) or lookup fields in CRM like Accountid, ParentCustomerid, territoryid(which are relationship fields(FK) with other entities) etc., data is moving perfectly else package is getting failed.

Here how can I load these missing attribute values into CRM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you are violating the referential integrity constraints. Try removing ( temporarily) all the constraints on the destination tables before executing your package.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I have an option like "Remove Unresolvable References".. by checking this option, all referential fields were left blank and all other fields got loaded into the destination. What we have to do next? In my scenario i have two tables account and contact, account has a lookup field of contact as contactid which is a auto generated field. When i load data it excluded contactid in account table. Here how can i load particular account's related contact?

Comment: Thanks.. i updated account table after loading contact table.. it loaded perfectly...